# Nginx : how to regrex on Nginx url wildcard?

Tags: nginx

I want to configure regular expression on location
example: `/order-service/js/app.js` or `/order-service/js/xxxx/xxxxxx/app.js` like this,

So order-service will be set `proxy_pass://order-service/js/xxxx/xxxxxx/app.js` 
that means I will get 2 variables, one is order-service, and another is `/js/xxxx/xxxx/app.js`, so how can I write the URL wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/(order-service)(/js/.*) {}
```

or more specific:

```
location ~ ^/(order-service)(/js.*/app.js) {}
```